# C++ algorithm for sliding window on container

Tags: c++

I found myself writing a hand-crafted `while`-loop today like so:

```
std::list<T> foo; // In my case, map, but list is simpler
auto currentPoint = std::begin(foo);
while (true) {
    // Let's say the container has > 0 elements
    auto nextPoint = std::next(currentPoint);
    if (nextPoint == std::end(foo))
        break;

    // Do stuff with *currentPoint and *nextPoint
    currentPoint = nextPoint;
}
```

Following Sean Parent's advice ([no raw loops](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning)), I tried to replace that `while`-loop with a standard algorithm and a nice lambda, but I couldn't find a suitable algorithm that would iterate through the map on a sliding window (2-elements at a time). A simple `for_each` with `next` doesn't work, as `for_each` passes a reference to the element to the lambda, and I can't call `next` on it.

```
std::for_each(
    std::begin(skylineMap),
    // Let's say the container has > 0 elements
    std::prev(std::end(skylineMap)),
    [&](const typename decltype(skylineMap)::value_type &currentPoint) {
        auto nextPoint = ???; // next(currentPoint) wouldn't work, of course
        // Do stuff with currentPoint and nextPoint
    }
);
```

EDIT: Remove example of operation I wanted to do; the example seemed to confuse more than clarify.

Comment: Check partitioning/set algorithms like [`std::partition_copy()`]( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy), could be a good inspiration.

Comment: Are you suggesting this because of my `(currentPoint != nextPoint)` condition? Sorry to have misled; but in general, it could be any operation on `currentPoint` and `nextPoint`. Otherwise, I don't see how `partition_copy` would help me.

Comment: Loops are fine.  Didn't Sean give any advice on the conditions when replacing them with `for_each` would be appropriate?

Comment: I think that the way STL algorithms are made, they will always dereference the iterators in order to hide them from your lambda, because it should not know about these details. What you could do is write your own loop algorithm, say `for_each_2` which would call the lambda with `current` and `next` as arguments.

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, of course, he did. I just threw that out as context. I'm happy with the loop, but would be happier with an algorithm.

Comment: @user846250: Perhaps I should roll my own. I'm not as familiar with <algorithm> as I should be, and wondered if I was missing something.

Comment: If you find this is an algorithm you use often, you can make a template function for it. Mostly they are not very complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options for doing this with pre-existing functions.

One is to use a zip-type function, such as the `std::transform` overload with 5 arguments, and two ranges: `[c.begin() + 1, c.end())` and `[c.begin(), c.end() - 1)`.  Or `for_each` with `boost::zip_iterator`.  This is mostly only useful for windows of size 2.

Another is to use `for_each` with `boost::counting_iterator`, so that your callback actually receives an iterator that it can advance to access adjacent elements.  This would be useful when your callback knows the size of the range it wants to use.

You can also combine them, using `boost::zip_iterator` on `boost::counting_iterator` to pass a `[begin, end)` pair of iterators to the callback.  That's useful because it lets the caller determine the window size.

For a one-off, I would just write the for-loop.

And finally, if you use this often you can package up that for-loop into your own algorithm function -- they are straight-forward templates.  This will probably be have much lower complexity than using any of the above.