# Having an iterator as a sliding window of 3 elements that can overshoot bounds (possibly using Boost)

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

Having read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656683/c-algorithm-for-sliding-window-on-container) and exploring [Boost.Iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html), I want to see if I can make a sliding window of size 3 iterate through a single vector where the final iteration has an 'empty third element'.

Assuming that the vector size is >= 2, an example:

```
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
```

We will always start on index 1 because this algorithm I'm implementing requires a 'previous' element to be present and does *not* need to operate on the first element (so we would iterate from `i = 1` while `i < size()`):

```
    V
[a, b, c]
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
```

when I move to the next iteration, it would look like:

```
       V
   [b, c, d]
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
```

and upon reaching the last element in the iteration, it would have this:

```
                   V
               [f, g, EMPTY]
{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
```

What I want is to be able to grab the "prev" and check if "hasNext" and grab the next element if available. My goal is very clean modern C++ code, and it not doing bookkeeping of tracking pointers/references for three different elements makes the code a lot cleaner:

```
for (const auto& it : zippedIterator(dataVector)) {
    someFunc(it.first, triplet.second);

    if (someCondition(it.second) && hasThirdElement) {
        anotherFunc(it.second, it.third)
    }
}
```

I was trying to see if this is possible with boost's zip iterator, but I don't know if it allows me to overshoot the end and have some empty value.

I've thought of doing some hacky stuff like having a dummy final element, but then I have to document it and I'm trying to write clean code with zero hacky tricks.

I was also going to roll my own iterator but apparently [std::iterator is deprecated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator).

I also don't want to create a copy of the underlying vector since this will be used in a tight loop that needs to be fast and copying everything would be very expensive for the underlying objects. It doesn't need to be extremely optimized, but copying the iterator values into a new array is out of the question.

Comment: "*I was also going to roll my own iterator but apparently std::iterator is deprecated.*" `std::iterator` is not essential for writing an iterator.

Comment: "*upon reaching the last element in the iteration, it would have this:*" So, do you want to invent values regardless of how much of the range is outside of the range of the actual container, or do you just want to invent a value when the last element is outside of the range? Because the latter is a pretty specific request.

Comment: Any value of out of range would work, it doesn't have to be an invented value of the same type. The only requirement I have is that it knows when it's out of range and if I try to proceed due to a bug in the code, it should crash/assert/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this were a matter of simply having a sized window into a range, then what you really want is to have a range that you can advance. In your case, that range is 3 elements long, but there's no reason that a general mechanism couldn't allow for a variable-sized range. It would just be a pair of iterators, such that you can ++ or -- both of them at the same time.

The problem you run into is that you want to manufacture an element if the subrange is off the end of the range. That complicates things; that would require proxy-iterators and so forth.

If you want a solution for your specific case (a 3-element sized range, where the last element can be manufactured if it's off the end of the main range), then you first need to decide if you want to have an actual type for this. That is, is it *worth* implementing a whole type, rather than a couple of one-off utility functions?

My way to handle this would be to redefine the problem. What you seem to have is a current element, just like any other iteration. But you want to be able to access the previous element. And you want to be able to peek ahead to the next element; if there is none, then you want to manufacture some default. So... perform iteration, but write a couple of utility functions that let you access what you need from the current element.

```
for(auto curr = ++dataVector.begin();
    curr != dataVector.end();
    ++curr)
{
  someFunc(prevElement(curr), *curr);

  auto nextIt = curr + 1;
  if(nextIt != dataVector.end() && someCondition(*curr))
    anotherFunc(*curr, *nextIt)
}
```

`prevElement` is a simple function that accesses the element before the given iterator.

```
template<typename It>
  //requires BidirectionalIterator<It>
decltype(auto) prevElement(It curr) {return *(--curr);}
```

If you want to have a function to check the next element and manufacture a value for it, that can be done too. This one has to return a prvalue of the element, since we may have to manufacture it:

```
template<typename It>
  //requires ForwardIterator<It>
auto checkNextElement(It curr, It endIt)
{
  ++curr;
  if(curr == endIt)
    return std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type{};
  return *curr;
}
```

Yes, this isn't all clever, with special range types and the like. But the stuff you're doing is hardly common, particularly the having to manufacture the next element as you do. By keeping things simple and obvious, you make it easy for someone to read your code without having to understand some specialized sub-range type.